# calculation of an Orlicz norm

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, orlicz-spaces

I would need, if possible, some help with the calculation of the Orlicz norm of a random variable $X$.

I have this function:

$\phi(x)=x\ln(1+x)$,

and I need to compute

$\inf c>0$ s.t. $E \left[\phi\left(\frac{|X|}{c}\right) \right]\leq 1$.

I cannot find a solution for this (sorry...), so any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: It will be difficult to answer without any information on $X$. What do you know about this random variable?

Comment: good question - it is a Bernoulli r.v., say it takes values $a$ and $b$ with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ resp. So direct calculation of the expectation is possible for given $c$.